# setting enable indentity insert on multiple tables where some of them already had id ON

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to import data into db.
In order to do so I need to set `indentity insert on`.
Setting this with `edit mapping` for 500+ tables is not an option.

So I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687575/delete-all-data-in-sql-server-database)

But some of that tables already have it set to ON so Puting this in one query will produce error on 1 wrong statement and stopped.
How to force it to ignore errors end go to next statement until it will try to set it ON for all tables?

Answer (score 1):

How are you importing your data? You might want to take a look at [Keep Identity Values When Bulk Importing Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx).

You can only turn [IDENTITY_INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188059.aspx)  on for one table at a time (per session). If you need to you can use this query to generate a script to turn IDENTITY_INSERT off for every applicable table.

```
select 
    N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + quotename(s.name) + N'.' + quotename(o.name) + N' OFF'
from 
    sys.objects o
        inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
where 
    o.type = 'U' and
    c.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

-- for sql server 2005 and on
    begin try

```
   set identity_insert (table 1 name) on
end try

begin catch

    print ' table 1 already on'
end catch

 begin try

   set identity_insert (table 2 name) on

end try

begin catch

    print ' table 2 already on'

end catch
```